# Screen resolution VS2008 to WM6 Emulator vs Device, why is it different?

Tags: pocketpc

When I debug a VS2008 WM project in the emulator, it all works as expected, but when I select a device as the target for testing, the entire application gets hosed, appearing in the upper left of the display, distorted.  How can I make the display appear the same as in the emulator?

Comment: What's the native resolution of the device you're using?

Comment: That was it, different than the emulator, thanks.

Comment: I had the hunch it might be ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that the device uses different screen resolution and that the controls are not scaling properly.

The solution for this was to set the main form's AutoScaleMode to Dpi (default was Inherit).